# Reporting in selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with ruby 1.9.3,
I am writing test cases using Test::Unit::TestCase
I want some kind of report for my output result, please suggest me and give the code to implement

Comment: No one can help you this way.. rather tell us the what html you are hitting using selenium.. then let us know which part you want to store as a report.. if this what you don't what..then let us know what do you mean by report?

Comment: Report means just what test cases are passed, what are the failure bla bla

Answer (score 0):

This is about ruby unit test report, not about selenium.

Try [ci_reporter](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/ci_reporter/) via `gem install ci_reporter`.

Here's a simple Rakefile example:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'

Rake::TestTask.new(:unittest) do |t|
  t.pattern = 'tests/*_test.rb'
  t.verbose = true
  t.warning = true
end
```

Then run your unit tests via:

```
$ rake ci:setup:testunit unittest
```

Finally you should fine the XML format test results under ./reports/

Comment: I dont have rake file

Answer (score 0):

you can add following code in `env.rb`

```
----------------------------------------------
require 'report_builder'

World(PageObject::PageFactory)

ReportBuilder.configure do |config|
  config.report_path = 'test_report'
  config.report_types = [:html]
  config.report_title = 'Test Results'
  config.include_images = false
  config.additional_info = {browser: 'Chrome', environment: 'Stage 5'}
end
```

and try to run the test using the following command

```
cucumber folder_name/ URL='your.url.com' --tags @yourtagsinfeature1 --tags @yourtagsinfeature1 -f html -o report_file_name.html
```